# How handle silent notifications in iOS

Tags: objective-c, background, parse-platform, push-notification

I need to fetch data from parse SDK and update in core data after receiving push notification(silent notification)in foreground and background.how to receive silent push notification  and update data(without on click of notification).Here my code is

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
 /*
 //notification data  format from server 
  { "operation": "Update", 
  “Element”: “1234”, 
  "action": "db" }

//after receiving update notification ,i should fetch that unique   element(1234) data from parse and save  data into database.

*/

if ([[userInfo  objectForKey:@"operation"] isEqualToString:@"Update"])
{
    NSLog(@"update notication called");
 //fetching  data and  updating database using updateDatabase method ,its implemented in some other class.
    [database updateDatabase:[userInfo objectForKey:@“Element”]];

}
}
```

this is  silent notification, So how to handle silent notification in iOS. thanks

Comment: So is that method called? What is actually wrong?

Comment: In foreground it is calling ,in back ground it wont...

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable the background mode for that. Click on your Project Name in the file inspector, then select your target and select the tab "Capabilities". Now turn "Background Modes" on and select "Push Notifications".

Answer (score 0):

Modify your payload and make sure you've content-available set to '1'. This tag is required for silent notification. Without this the payload will be a non-silent notification.

```
{ 
  aps: {
          content-available: 1,
          sound: "default"
       }
}
```